# CSS Navigation Bar coloring problems

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am creating a navigation bar for a website, and I am not having the background color of the nav bar be displayed. When the `nav` tag has `float: left;` in the CSS, the color for the background doesn't show. When the `nav` tag doesn't have `float: left;`, the background color shows. How can I make the background color present while `nav` has `float: left;`?

```
<body>
    <div id="menubar" class="centered">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="book.html">Booking</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>

@charset "UTF-8";
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: source-sans-pro;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
nav {
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
    float: left;
}
li {
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: The HTML and the CSS are seperate documents, the formatting just didn't quite work out. And yes, I linked the stylesheet to the HTML document.

Comment: I see the color just fine http://jsfiddle.net/jqxZ3/ ..just changed to pink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fiddle shows that when your nav is floated, the background color appears:

http://jsfiddle.net/DhAsa/

Maybe your question needed to be the other way around? If so, adding `overflow:hidden` to your `nav` css declaration should do the trick. (or whatever way you would like to clear [floated elements](https://www.google.com/search?q=clearing%20floated%20elements&oq=clearing%20floated%20e&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.4220j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

Comment: Adding the overflow fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

When I put your code into a test HTML document, the navbar displays fine in all browsers that I tested with.

IE - fine
Firefox - fine 
Chrome - fine

What browser are you using?

Amar

Comment: I was using Safari on OS X